# How do I create a document for a user as soon as user registers with firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, routes, next.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a user document as soon as a user sign's up. I am using firebase right now but I haven't been able to trigger the document creation process.

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, Email, Password)
            .then(async (userCredential) => {
                // Signed in
                const user = userCredential.user;
                setUID(user.uid);
                console.log("User has been created with ", user.uid);
                await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
                    name: `${FirstName} ${SecondName}`,
                    email: `${Email}`,
                    uid: user.uid,
                    metadata: user.metadata,
                    phone: user.phoneNumber,
                    provider: user.providerId,
                    orders: [],
                    token: "",
                    address: {},
                    cartID: "",
                    wishlist: [],
                    servicesHistory: [],
                    createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
                });
                uploadImages();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                setSignUpError(error.Message);
            });
```

The above is the code I'm using to create a document.

**What I think the issue is**

Since I'm a beginner, please take this with a grain of salt. But I feel like the issue is as followed

-> I create a new user 
-> The useAuthState changes
-> On the change of AuthState, the page get's redirected to `/home`
-> The `/register` page doesn't complete the function as it is redirected to the `/home` page

This is the issue I think is occuring, any input on how I can solve this is really helpful.

In case anyone is wonder, this is what the SignUp component looks like

```
const SignUp = (props: any) => {
    const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);

    const router = useRouter();
    if (loading) {
        return <Loading />;
    }
    if (user) {
        router.push("/home");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <main className="min-h-[80vh] flex justify-center items-center my-12">
                <SignUpForm />
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you consider not using `useAuthState` when the user is still signing up? You can instead handle the same flow in the `then` of your `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I would love to do that, I don't want signed in users to be able to visit the ```sign-up``` page. If I try the way you have suggested, I would have to end up making a compromise in that field. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you for your input though!

Comment: In the JavaScript SDK, calling `onAuthStateChanged` (which is what your `useAuthState` likely wraps) returns an unsubscribe function - so you can stop the auth state listener after you first get a value. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Answer (score 0):

hi try do it like this

```
const doc = await setDoc(
      collection(db, "users", user.uid),
      {
        ......
      }
    );
```

but i think you need an extra table if you can call it that

```
const doc = await setDoc(
      collection(db, "users", user.uid, "info"),
      {
        ......
      }
    );
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell me more about what info is? just tried what you told me, it did not work. Thank you for the input though!

Comment: the info is stands as a title for the table inside the user in my case I do it like this:  function NewRecipe() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const createNewRecipe = async () => {
    const doc = await addDoc(
      collection(db, "users", session?.user?.email!, "recipes"),
      {
        prompt: "",
        userId: session?.user?.email!,
        title: "",
        ingredients: [],
        instructions: [],

      }
    );

    router.push(`/recipes/${doc.id}`);
  };

export default NewRecipe;